# NuGet TypeScript tooling:Why the added version of typescript compiler is still not available?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

**Context**

I am using VS 2017.3. Just created an ASP MVC project, then added two nuget packages,

- Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler v2.5.3
- Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild v2.5.3

When trying to configure the typescript build, I see that TypeScript version 2.5 is not available.

**Question**

What am I missing? I thought that adding those nuget packages will the project (and build) independent from the development machine state of installation...

**What I've tried so far**

- Unloaded, reloaded the project
- Exit VS,
- restart VS Build the project

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the added version of typescript compiler is still not available?

You need download and install the typescripts SDK version 2.5.3 from the [download center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258) and restarted Visual Studio.

The NuGet package of `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` is used for **providing the TypeScript MSBuild task, and matching compiler version**.

[image]

Starting with Visual Studio 2017, we could have multiple TypeScript versions installed and choose specific versions for each of your projects, after you install `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` package, you can choose specific versions for your project, for example, I have install several versions of the  Typescripts SDKs on my machine:

[image]

Then I install that package to my ASP MVC project with the version **2.3**, restart the Visual Studio, re-open project, on the Typescripts build tab, you will notice **the matching version of Typescript 2.3 is selected by default**:

[image]

Of course, you can manually select other version of Typescript.

Comment: Many thanks, it works. 1) I would recommend to rephrase the comment line of the MSBuild task, which states '...and matching compiler version...'. Actually there is _no_ dependency at all for this package, so there is no "and".  2) About the compiler package: I think I am not alone who supposes, if I install the compiler package, then I will have a compiler installed. In reality I had to install the SDK to have a compiler... Besides the misleading name, the question arises, then what the compiler package installs?

Comment: @g.pickardou, That is just a tool package, which include the typescript compiler. AFAIK, TypeScriptTeam provide this package for those who want to get the typescript compiler in an easier way.

Comment: Said another way...So what's the point of even having a NuGet package for TypeScript if we still must download and install the SDK anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is to the point, but perhaps some further explanation will prove helpful.

In Visual Studio 2017, the typescript compiler provided with the nuget package is only used by msbuild, but the TypeScript language service relies on a TypeScript SDK to be installed on the machine. Quoting from a github issue, ["Currently, compile on save in VS requires a matching version of the TypeScript language service to be installed on the machine."](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27567#issuecomment-445119013)

Although the question is tagged with Visual Studio 2017, it might be of interest that this will be amended with Visual Studio 2019. From the release notest of the release candidate: ["The JavaScript/TypeScript language service will now be automatically loaded in projects that have the TypeScript NuGet package or npm package installed (TypeScript 3.2 and up is supported from the NuGet package and TypeScript 2.1 and up is supported from the npm package)."](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#jsts)